# Call python object - odoo 9

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

In python console(jupyter) I use a python library in the form:

```
class SomeClass(object) 
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        ... 
    def fct1(self):
        ...
    return something
```

And I get no problem creating an object with:

```
x = SomeClass(arg1,arg2)
```

I would like to use those methods in Odoo. 
I tried the following:

```
class SomeClass(**models.Model**)
    def **connect**(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
    def fct1(self):
        ...
    return something
```

Replacing "object" with "model,Models" to have it as an odoo class + renaming **init** with a method name.

But

```
x = connect(arg1,arg2)
```

returns :

NameError: global name 'connect' is not defined

How would I use my python library in Odoo (new API)?

TIA

## UPDATE:

I also tried calling

> x= self.connect(arg1,arg2) or
>    x=SomeClass.connect(arg1,arg2)

but it return "None" when I "print x". I think an instance is not created

Comment: if you want the name to be **connect** you should use class name as **connect** and `__init__` is a constructor function

Comment: tnx for rply. I'm afraid I don't understand your answer. I updated my question maybe it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to [zbik](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/user/34055) for the answer:

myclass.py in folder myaddons

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def _test(self,a,b):
        return a+b
```

in other Odoo class:

```
from openerp.addons.myaddons.myclass import MyClass
...
x = MyClass('Hello')
y = x._test(2,3)
...
print x.name
> Hello
print y
> 5
```